# SSISDB - Deploy project using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, deployment, ssis

I am trying to deploy SSIS project into SSISDB using T-SQL. Say in case of any error while deploying, error messaged got logged into catalog.operation_messages view.

Now if I execute same deploy statement in Explicit SQL transaction and if any error occurs at time of deployment I am not able to find error logged into catalog.operation_message.

Ex.

```
BEGIN

BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN TRAN1
Declare @folder_id bigint
EXEC SSISDB.catalog.create_folder @folder_name='test1', @folder_id=@folder_id OUTPUT
Select @folder_id
EXEC SSISDB.catalog.set_folder_description @folder_name='test1', @folder_description='test1'

--Deploy

DECLARE @ProjectBinary as varbinary(max)
DECLARE @operation_id as bigint
Set @ProjectBinary = (SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Test\MyProject.ispac', SINGLE_BLOB) as BinaryData)
Exec SSISDB.catalog.deploy_project @folder_name = 'test1', @project_name = 'ABC', @Project_Stream = @ProjectBinary, @operation_id = @operation_id out


COMMIT  TRAN TRAN1
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE()
COMMIT TRAN TRAN1
END CATCH
END
```

This return me error message something like 
Failed to deploy project. For more information, query the operation_messages view for the operation identifier '34704'.

But when I query view and try looking for same I am not able to find any message logged by this operation_Id, is it rollbacked? if yes by which process? how I can retain it?

Help me in understanding it.

Comment: There is a generally a bit of lag. Are you able to query now?

Comment: No, I am not still able to see that. There is something else running behind the scenes which I am still trying to figure out.

Comment: I did executed trace for SQL Transaction. I have not found any single difference between them(running within transaction & without transaction). Everything is same.

Comment: even running code between simple BEGIN TRAN & COMMIT TRAN, doesn't let SQL Server to save message in its catalog.internal_messages view

Comment: Are you able to deploy using BIDS/SSDT?

Comment: Deploying is not an issue, in my lab\test environment I introduced error purposely, I know what is the error. What I am looking for is logging of this error into SSISDB internal.operation_messages table. 
Say if we deliver it as a product and if it fails and in transaction, how would I know that it fail for that reason?

So my concern is, logging of error messages into SSISDB while executing deployment procedure in transaction.

Comment: It seems that`catalog.operation_messages` does not log messages related to deployment. It logs messages that describe the steps of package execution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82287/discussion-between-ashish-and-sourav-agasti).